# How to create multiple IDS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I create multiple ID'S from the script to perform several open-transitons? `document.getelementbyname` does not seem to work form me.

As you can see if you scroll towards the middle of the demo result window you will see the first button opening both transitions while the second button (three dots) does nothing, I want the second button to open the bottom transition on its own.

[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BNvobY)

**SCRIPT**

```
 /*!
  * classie - class helper functions
  * from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo
  * 
  * classie.has( elem, 'my-class' ) -> true/false
  * classie.add( elem, 'my-new-class' )
  * classie.remove( elem, 'my-unwanted-class' )
  * classie.toggle( elem, 'my-class' )
  */

 /*jshint browser: true, strict: true, undef: true */
 /*global define: false */

 (function (window) {

     'use strict';

     // class helper functions from bonzo https://github.com/ded/bonzo

     function classReg(className) {
         return new RegExp("(^|\\s+)" + className + "(\\s+|$)");
     }

     // classList support for class management
     // altho to be fair, the api sucks because it won't accept multiple classes at once
     var hasClass, addClass, removeClass;

     if ('classList' in document.documentElement) {
         hasClass = function (elem, c) {
             return elem.classList.contains(c);
         };
         addClass = function (elem, c) {
             elem.classList.add(c);
         };
         removeClass = function (elem, c) {
             elem.classList.remove(c);
         };
     } else {
         hasClass = function (elem, c) {
             return classReg(c).test(elem.className);
         };
         addClass = function (elem, c) {
             if (!hasClass(elem, c)) {
                 elem.className = elem.className + ' ' + c;
             }
         };
         removeClass = function (elem, c) {
             elem.className = elem.className.replace(classReg(c), ' ');
         };
     }

     function toggleClass(elem, c) {
         var fn = hasClass(elem, c) ? removeClass : addClass;
         fn(elem, c);
     }

     var classie = {
         // full names
         hasClass: hasClass,
         addClass: addClass,
         removeClass: removeClass,
         toggleClass: toggleClass,
         // short names
         has: hasClass,
         add: addClass,
         remove: removeClass,
         toggle: toggleClass
     };

     // transport
     if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
         // AMD
         define(classie);
     } else {
         // browser global
         window.classie = classie;
     }

 })(window);


 /**
  * main.js
  * http://www.codrops.com
  *
  * Licensed under the MIT license.
  * http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php
  * 
  * Copyright 2014, Codrops
  * http://www.codrops.com
  */ (function () {

     var bodyEl = document.body,
         content = document.querySelector('.content-wrap'),
         openbtn = document.getElementById('open-button'),
         closebtn = document.getElementById('close-button'),
         isOpen = false;

     function init() {
         initEvents();
     }

     function initEvents() {
         openbtn.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
         if (closebtn) {
             closebtn.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu);
         }

         // close the menu element if the target it´s not the menu element or one of its descendants..
         content.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
             var target = ev.target;
             if (isOpen && target !== openbtn) {
                 toggleMenu();
             }
         });
     }

     function toggleMenu() {
         if (isOpen) {
             classie.remove(bodyEl, 'show-menu');
         } else {
             classie.add(bodyEl, 'show-menu');
         }
         isOpen = !isOpen;
     }

     init();

 })();
```

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you're asking, but JS is case sensitive, and normally, `document.getElementBy` is camelCase.

Comment: `document.getelementbyname` won't work. It should be `document.getElementsByName`

Comment: All I see are two sets of 3 dots chilling in the demo

Comment: You have to click it, the first set of three dots will open two black boxes, while the second set does nothing. I want the second set of three dots to open the bottom box